# Point DNS to subdirectory on heroku rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, masking, forwarding

We have a rails app that generates subdirectories for a user
`example.herokuapp.com/user1directory` &
`example.herokuapp.com/user2directory`

Is there a way to point DNS for a url to that specific directory of the rails app, without any silly hacks?

Ideally what we need is `user1website` -> `example.herokuapp.com/user1directory` but masks it while showing any further subdirectories / pages.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you find a workaround?

Comment: For now I'm just using routing to point each to url based on the domain. I made a question based on making that dynamic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346108/rails-dynamic-routing-based-on-host-id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's imposible without hacks & proxies. Just because HTTP and DNS are not at the same level.