# Rails - Dynamic routing based on host & ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, ruby-on-rails-3.2, url-routing, rails-routing

I have a rails application that contains many user pages. When a user wants to point a domain at this page, how would I do that?

Right now I've tested out this, and it works -
`root :to => "controller#show", :id => 4, :constraints => {:host => "www.exampleurl.com"}`

but need to convert this to be dynamic, so that after I migrate a column into the model called
`domain` it checks `domain` and serves it the proper ID.

something like -
`root :to => 'controller#show', :id => ':id', :constraints => {:host => ':domain'}`

What would something like this look like?

Comment: Anyone have suggestions??